# to make nodejs block calling other functions till one function is completly executed

Tags: node.js

how to execute the whole function completly which has mysql queries and then moving on to another function in nodejs.As nodejs is asynchronous and non-blocking in nature.It is first executing the non sql part in one function then moving on to another function to execute non-sql part and finally executes the mysql queries in both the functions.

Comment: Don't artificially block! Use callbacks, promises, or investigate async.waterfall if necessary.

Comment: You can't block waiting for an async operation to finsh in Javascript.  There are literally more than a thousand questions on this topic here on stack overflow.  Instead, you register a callback or return a promise and you put the code that needs to use the async result in the callback or promise `.then()` handler.  In ES6, you can also use async/await, but that's just simpler syntax for promises (you still need to understand how it all works).

Comment: You can only get specific help if you show your actual code.  Questions about code here on stack overflow should ALWAYS include that code.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement it is best to use something like the async waterfall method.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        //Do first task send result if needed to call back on success
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        //Do Second task send result if needed to call back on success
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // Execute the mysql task
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```